# How to determine if JSON array is set and output it if yes

Tags: php, arrays, json

So, I have following JSON I get with `var_dump()`:

```
array(36) {
    [0]=> string(4) "null" 
    [1]=> string(56) "{"article":"Bread","==":"String"}" 
    [2]=> string(68) "{"article":"Beef","amount":3,"==":"String"}" 
    [3]=> string(4) "null" 
    [4]=> string(52) "{"article":"Water","==":"String"}" 
    [5]=> string(4) "null" 
    [6]=> string(4) "null" 
    [7]=> string(4) "null"
}
```

Now I would like to check whether 0,1,2... is set or not, then output the "article" and the amount if any is set.

What would be the most optimized way to do that? Ugly 7 if's wouldn't be it, or?

Comment: A loop? Hard to know without any context...

Comment: It doesn't look like JSON. Looks like var_dump(). Use json_encode($your_array) to show real JSON.

Comment: this looks more like a string of chars which can be encoded to json.

Comment: @zoonman json_encode returns following http://pastebin.com/F94PabFX Currently it's the output of var_dump()

Comment: The much easier way to use array_filter($your_array). In your case array_filter don't require second parameter, because your array contain null, which will be treated as false and omitted in results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [foreach structure](http://php.net/foreach) to iterate over your array and [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) to transform your JSON into a PHP object and then print a specific property.

```
foreach ($your_array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value != 'null') {
        $data = json_decode($value);
        echo $data->article;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, so we got 'article' now but how to check if it's set or not and also how to check if the amount is set?

Comment: Did you understand how the `foreach` statement works? Read its documentation on the PHP website (I linked it in the answer). You don't need 7 if's, just one inside the loop.

Comment: Oh damn, I shame myself. Thank you! I thought the if is checking if the array is set, not one value of it